# Bash Script Loop

Tags: bash, shell, loops, unix

so I am trying to make a bash script loop that takes a users file name they want and the number of files they want and creates empty files. I made the script but I keep getting the error "./dog.sh: line 6: 0]: No such file or directory". I'm new to bash script and don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be awesome thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "what file name do you want?"; read filename
echo "how many files do you want"; read filenumber

x=$filenumber
if [$x < 0] 
then
touch $fiename$filenumber
x=$((x--))

fi
```

Comment: Consider running your script through [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) first to clear up the basic issues, then ask about the remainder.

Comment: `x=$((x--))` is really funny `;)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's a typo: $fiename instead of $filename

also, you might want some kind of loop like so:

```
x=1
while [ $x -le $filenumber ]; do
    touch $filename$x
    let x=x+1
done
```

Comment: That fixed my problem of running it but all I get is just one file with the number. ex. dog and 7 = dog7. I need it to make dog1, dog2, dog3,... dog7.

Comment: Thanks! I see where my problem is now. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in $(seq "$filenumber"); do touch "$filename$x"; done
```

`seq $filenumber` produces a list of numbers from 1 to `$filenumber`.  The  `for` loop assigns `x` to each of these numbers in turn.  The `touch` command is run for each value of `x`.

#### Alternative

In `bash`, if we can type the correct file number into the command line, the same thing can be accomplished without a `for` loop:

```
$ touch myfile{1..7}
$ ls
myfile1  myfile2  myfile3  myfile4  myfile5  myfile6  myfile7
```

`{1..7}` is called "brace expansion".  Bash will expand the expression `myfile{1..7}` to the list of seven files that we want.

Brace expansion does have a limitation.  It does not support shell variables.  So, `touch myfile{1..$filenumber}` would not work.  We have to enter the correct number in the braces directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "what file name do you want?"; read filename
echo "how many files do you want"; read filenumber

x=$filenumber

while [ $x -gt 0 ]; do

    touch $filename$x   
    x=$(( $x - 1))
done
```

Comment: trying to keep this as true to your example as possible.